# Visualforce dropdown rendering invisible values

Tags: visualforce, picklist, error

I have a Visualforce page using Lightning stylesheets with reRender attributes on the time selectList.

For some odd reason, *some users* are experiencing intermittent issues with the picklists rendering the values invisible.

Below is the code snippet and a screenshot of the issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
<label class="slds-form-element__label">Appointment Date</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <div class="slds-select_container">
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!BookingDate}" styleClass="slds-select">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="--Select a date--"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!BDate}" />
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="time" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
<label class="slds-form-element__label">Appointment Date</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <div class="slds-select_container">
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!BookingHour}" id="time" label="Appointment Time" styleClass="slds-select">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:** The time is bound to a Items set with hardcoded time strings

```
Set<String> DayEvent = new Set<String>{'','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30',
        '13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30', '15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30'};
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
public List<SelectOption> getBDate() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if (weekdays != null){

            for (datetime s: weekdays){ // Iterating over set date AllWeekdaysBetweenStartEnd
                options.add(new SelectOption(s.format('d/MM/YYYY'),s.format('d/MM/YYYY'))); // Formatting the datetime to String e.g. Wednesday 8 Aug
            }
        }
        system.debug('does this event get processed');
        return options;
    }


    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {

        Set<String> DayEvent = new Set<String>{'','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30',
            '13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30', '15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30'};
        if (weekdays != null){
            datetime day1   = weekdays[0];
            datetime day2   = weekdays[1];
            datetime day3   = weekdays[2];
            datetime day4   = weekdays[3];
            datetime day5   = weekdays[4];
            system.debug('day1: ' +day1);
            system.debug('day2: ' +day2);
            system.debug('day3: ' +day3);
            system.debug('day4: ' +day4);
            system.debug('day5: ' +day5);
            if (evnt != null){
                for (onboarding_call__c ob : evnt){
                    obDate = ob.StartDate__c.format('d/MM/YYYY');
                    system.debug('obDate: ' + obDate);
                    if (BookingDate == day1.format('d/MM/YYYY')){
                        if (obDate == BookingDate){
                            if (ob.Time__c == '09:00'){
                                if (DayEvent.contains('09:00')){
                                    DayEvent.remove('09:00');
                                }
                            }
                            if (ob.Time__c == '09:30'){
                                if (DayEvent.contains('09:30')){
                                    DayEvent.remove('09:30');
                                    system.debug('DayEvent: ' + DayEvent);
                                }
                            }
                            .... // truncated to save space
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //String BookingHour {get;set;}
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (String s: DayEvent){ // Iterating over set date AllWeekdaysBetweenStartEnd
            options.add(new SelectOption(s,s)); // Formatting the datetime to String e.g. Wednesday 8 Aug
        }
        system.debug('DayEvent: ' + DayEvent);
        system.debug('******BookingHour******: ' + BookingHour );
        system.debug('options: ' + options);
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: I've included the source of Items in the original edit post, thanks. @AdrianLarson

Comment: No you haven't. You included `DayEvent` but gave no clear indication how it is at all related.

Comment: @AdrianLarson apologies, I've updated it with another code block edit

Comment: Also made an edit in there to specify that only some users are affected.

Comment: Hi What is you VF page <apex:page configuration parameters? for me it is purely CSS issue what you see if you remove the style class